# how to stop change instance when collision stops in game maker studio?

Tags: game-maker

```
Collision Event with object obj_cu:

for all obj_lamp: change the instance into object obj_lamo_light, not performing events
for all obj_arrow: change the instance into object obj_arrow_move, not performing events
```

where obj_lamo_light contains 3 sub iamges and obj_Arrow_move contains 3 sub images and I want to change them back to original objects when collision stops

Answer (score 0):

In the obj_lamp_light event, you could check whether or not your collision is still occurring, and change back if not.

```
if (collision_rectange(x, y, x + sprite_width, y + sprite_width, false, true) == noone)
{
    instance_change(obj_lamp, false);
}
```